# Filter merged cells workaround

Tags: excel, vba

**My problem:**

I have a spreadsheet with ids and names to search.
I thought I could use the filter option but the ids or names are in merged cells, so the filter option only returns the first row of data about an id or name.

**My spread sheet:**

```
    |Header 1| header 2| header 3| header 4|
    |--------------------------------------|
    |        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
    |id1     | name1   |  data2  |  data2  |
    |        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
    |--------------------------------------|
    |        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
    |id2     | name2   |  data2  |  data2  |
    |        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
    |--------------------------------------|
```

**What I've looked into:**

[How to sort/filter merged cells in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789992/how-to-sort-filter-merged-cells-in-excel)

Here I learned I would get all the data by unmerging the cells and giving them the same values. But there are a few problems:

1. This needs to be foolproof. It would be easy for a user to give them diferent names or ids by mistake
2. The names are often long, so merging the cells allows me to display them completely without column B being too wide
3. I have already written code to write and read this data, I would need to review how I navigate the spreadsheets

[How do I avoid merging cells vertically in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923474/how-do-i-avoid-merging-cells-vertically-in-excel)

This post suggested replacing the merged cell by a textbox on top of the cells, this could work if I had a formula to give each cell under the textbox the value in the textbox automatically. But again, not super foolproof or clean.

**The solution?**

I don't actually want to filter data. I want the user to get to the right part of the sheet by using a searchbox.

I was thinking a macro could work this way:

1. Listen for the user to apply a filter on a specific sheet, specific header
2. Store the address of the first visible cell under the header in variable MyCell
3. Remove the filter
4. Select MyCell

Is this possible?

**Alternative solution?**

1. Listen for the user to apply a filter on a specific sheet, specific header
2. Make the 2 rows under each filtered row visible

Could also work but not necessary.

Comment: If they just need to get to the right spot on the sheet, you could have the user input the name in a cell, or userform, and then do a `Range.Find` to bring them to the spot. There are several other ways too, if this isn't a serviceable solution.

Comment: @Kyle This could work. However I would like to use the filter option's search box if possible. The user might not know the correct name or id, so its nice to have suggestions. I suppose I could make an array of available names and ids but if I would like to spare myself the trouble if possible.

Comment: I would create a listbox of all possible entries, or a combobox that links to all possible entries, and have the user go through that. I recommend not trying to spare yourself a few lines of code for a less efficient, and more error prone, workaround.

Comment: @Kyle I will look into it. But I will leave the question open. It will be interesting to see if anybody knows how to do what I proposed.

Comment: It certainly is possible to read the users filter data, strip the filter, and get to the information. I just don't see the benefit of this method. Quite frankly I would just take out the merged cells. They only serve to cause headaches when you plan on using the data as opposed to just viewing it. See [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/09/26/copy-excel-table-filter-criteria-vba/) for how you might start reading filter data.

Comment: @Kyle Thank you. I understand the benefits of removing the merged cells. In my particular case, I found it best to keep the data this way for clarity. Each id coresponds to a person, each column coresponds to a day. Each row corresponds to an event. There are four possible events per day. This will not and cannot change. It is likely that unmerging the cells would cause confusion to the users when reading the report. Or editing. And I prefer to not explain to users why we need the same data multiple times. They might get the bright idea to merge the cells on their own....

Comment: Do you know the column the user will filter on? If so, it may be easier. Then you could just pull `Criteria1` from that specific `Filter` and use that. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979396/excel-vba-filter-change-event-handler) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @BenoitRanque, was the _searchbox_ solution what you were looking for, or would you prefer a different approach? In this latter case you may want to give more detail

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kyle for pointing me in the right dirrection. This is what I ended up doing:

```
|--------------------------------------|
|Header 1| header 2|                   |
|--------|---------| header 3| header 4|
|search: |         |                   |  
|--------------------------------------|
|        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
|id1     | name1   |  data2  |  data2  |
|        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
|--------------------------------------|
|        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
|id2     | name2   |  data2  |  data2  |
|        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
|--------------------------------------|
```

I placed a searchbox under the second header. I then inserted this code in the module page of the sheet the searchbox is in:

```
    Private SearchTerm As String
    Private SearchLoc As Range
    Private SearchOld As Range
    Private SearchStart As Range

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal SearchBox As Range)

    If SearchBox.Address = Me.Range("B2").Address And Not IsEmpty(Me.Range("B2").Value) Then

    If Not SearchOld Is Nothing Then
    Set SearchStart = SearchOld
    Set SearchOld = Nothing
    Else
    Set SearchStart = Range("B2")
    End If

    If Not SearchTerm = Trim(Me.Range("B2").Value) Then
    SearchTerm = Me.Range("B2").Value
    Set SearchStart = Range("B2")
    End If

    If Trim(SearchTerm) <> "" Then

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:A, B:B")
    Set SearchLoc = .Find(What:=SearchTerm, _
    After:=SearchStart, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    Searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    Searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False)

    If Not SearchLoc Is Nothing Then
    Set SearchOld = SearchLoc
    Application.Goto Cells(SearchLoc.Row, 1), True
    End If

    End With
    End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

This code was mostly <s>ripped</s> borrowed from here:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

I also used this reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

**What it does**

This code listens for any change on the worksheet. It then detects if that change happened in B2 and B2 is not empty. Then it checks if an anterior search was equal or not to the current one. If that is the case it looks for the next instance of the same searchTerm, else it searches from the top. It then goes to the result. If the user searches for something that does not exist if goes to the top.

A word of warning: in my case the searchbox is included in the columns that are searched. So if the user searches for something that does not exist it simply goes to the searchbox. If you use this code and move the searchbox, you would need to check that it does not loop indefinitly.

Thanks again to @Kyle